# mongodb architect design with hardware specification

Tags: mongodb

Currently we have one replica set of 3 members, 25 GB of data, normal cpu usage is 1.5 in both secondary, 0.5 in primary(read happen in secondary instance only), normally 1200 users hit our website. Now we have planned to increase the no of hit to our website. We are expecting about 5000 concurrent users to our website, can you please suggest no of instance needed to add in my replica set.

Current infra in our replica set:

```
1. Primary instance
CPUs: 16
RAM: 32 GB
HDD: 100 GB

2. Secondary instance
CPUs: 8
RAM: 16 GB
HDD: 100 GB

3. Secondary instance
CPUs: 8
RAM: 16 GB
HDD: 100 GB
```

Comment: This is a question regarding administration and maintenance of MongoDB, not about application development. I nominated your question for migration to https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application scales linearly with the number of users, the CPU capacity should not be a problem (does it? Only you can tell - we don't know what your application does).

The question is: how much do you expect your data to grow? When you currently have 25 GB of data and 16 GB of ram, 64% of your data fits into RAM. That likely means that many queries can be served directly from the RAM cache without hitting the hard drives. These queries are usually very fast. But when your working set increases further beyond the size of your RAM, you might experience some increased latency when accessing the data which now needs to be read from the hard drives (it depends, though: when your application interacts primarily with recent data and rarely with older data, you might not even notice much of a difference).

The solution to this is obvious: get more RAM. Should this not be an option (for example because the server reached the maximum RAM capacity the hardware allows), your next option is building a [sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-architectures-production/) where each shard is responsible for serving an interval of your data.